# I want to use vb script as the website .how to do it

Tags: web, vbscript

I create this code.

```
Dim msg, sapi
msg=InputBox("Enter your text","Talk it")
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak msg
```

and now i want to convert this into the website.
how it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely speculation (untested as I have currently no access to a suitable environment), but you might be able to do something like accept the text from a form and process it on the server using classic ASP and then the HTML5 `<audio>` tag for playback:

your form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <form action="speak.asp" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Enter your text</legend>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text..." name="line" ><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Talk it" >
            </fieldset>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

your asp and output HTML:

```vb
<%@ language="vbscript" %>
<%
     Dim msg, sapi, output
     msg = Request.QueryString("line")
     Set sapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
     ' save the speech to file
     set output = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
     output.Format.Type = 8 'SAFT11kHz8BitMono
     output.Open "output.wav", 3, false 
     set sapi.AudioOutputStream = output

     sapi.Speak msg
     sapi.WaitUntilDone -1
     output.Close 
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <audio controls>
         <source type="audio/wav" src="output.wav">
       </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

This assumes your web server has the speech API installed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The including of this code is quite simple. Using the the popular `<script>` tag for this task:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="textinput" size="30">
   <script type="text/vbscript">
    Sub SpeakIt
       Dim msg, sapi
       msg= textinput.Value
       Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
       sapi.Speak msg
     End Sub
   </script>
   <input type="button" value="speak" onClick="SpeakIt">
  </body>
</html>
```

Take an eye on the mentioned `script` tag, especially on the additional `type` attribute.

Keep also in mind, this code will be **only** executed in very few browsers. One of the most famous is the Internet Explorer.

Comment: Dear Sir, It work but.it open the dialogue box. i want it to open in the browser as web page???how to do it??

Comment: What exactly do want to convert into a webpage? Please, be more specific.

Comment: how to install speech api

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490042/microsoft-speech-api-5-1-5-3?rq=1 can help. I think you need version 5.3 instead of 5.4.